# hp monitor has no signal when i boot to ubuntu cd

Tags: ubuntu, display

When i boot to the cd on my emachines i have no problems and the disk has been tested in other pcs and laptops.  My son needs to work on our HP, but the monitor shows no signal when I boot to the cd.  The lights are flashing on the cd rom drive.  Does any body have a fix.  Last resort I can switch monitors.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Ubuntu disc are you using?

You may need to change the kernel mode settings and add "nomodeset" or "i915.modeset=1" at the end of the boot parameters. The parameters you need to add will depend on what hardware your HP computer has (namely what type of graphics card it uses).

See [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1467690) thread for more info.